# Count how many people join in 1st half and 2nd half in csv file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, count

Sample output:

[image: acreenshot of Sample output]

This code help to count how many people join in 1st half and in 2nd half of every year. This code is working fine but the code is too big and complex so can anyone make this code easy and small and if h2 is not available in print then we get the default value 0 then it's easy to read the result.

```
import csv

H1 = {}
H2 = {}



with open('1000 Records.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

for row in csv_reader:

    year_of_joining = row[17]

    half_of_joining = row[16]

    if half_of_joining == 'H1':
        H1[year_of_joining] = H1.get(year_of_joining, 0) + 1
    elif half_of_joining == 'H2':
        H2[year_of_joining] = H2.get(year_of_joining, 0) + 1

    dict_items_one = H1.items()
    sorted_item_one = sorted(dict_items_one)

    sorted_item_one_done = dict(sorted_item_one)

    dict_items_two = H2.items()
    sorted_item_two = sorted(dict_items_two)

    sorted_item_two_done = dict(sorted_item_two)

    result = {}
    for key in (H1.keys() or H2.keys()):
        if key in H1:
            result.setdefault(key, []).append(H1[key])
        if key in H2:
            result.setdefault(key, []).append(H2[key])

    sort_result = result.items()
    sort_result_start = sorted(sort_result)
    sort_result_done = dict(sort_result_start)

    for k, v in sort_result_done.items():
        print("people who join in H1 and H2: ", str(k) + ': ' + str(v))
```

Comment: Input sample would be helpful so that ppl don't have to understand your code to get what exactly is in the '1000 Records.csv'